# how to develop a social.framework iphone application

Tags: android, ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

In android, there is the ability for us to use intents to be able to have our application display in the list when another application wants to share images to, but what I am trying to figure out is how to accomplish the same thing with the iphone. I see that their is social.framework which allows us to see a list of social networks to share to. My question is is their a way for us to write an application to be added to that list so a user can share an image from another application to our custom application?

Answer (score 0):

No those social apps have been added to iOS itself. Thats why various iOS versions have only had some of them, like iOS 6 only had facebook and twitter. You'll note the ones you can share to are the ones that have been added to the iPhone settings screen and allow you to add an account to iOS. Third party apps can later request to use the iOS user's twitter account etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register "share" parameters in your app's plist file, then your app will appear in the system share menu. The menu will called by UIActivityViewController.

This file could help: [Document Interaction
Programming Topics for
iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS.pdf)